# Trying to learn php with html but I am having trouble submitting a form with a variable that is given by some javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

In the Html code below I grab the Ip address of the client and display it to them. I am still learning Javascript however and I am very confused with the line "$("#gfg").html(data.ip);" How would you rewrite this line to be more understandable? Additionally within the html file I would like to submit the information contained within gfg to the php form! I am very uncertain how to do this. :/ Sorry for the basic questions I am very new to this and still trying to understand just how javascript and php works. If there are any materials that you believe would help me please link them and I will be sure to study them!

HTML Script:

```
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <script>
    $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json",
      function(data) {
        // Setting text of element P with id gfg
        $("#gfg").html(data.ip);
      })
  </script>

  <p>
    Your Public IP Address is:
  </p>
  <p id="gfg"></p>

  <form id="ipsend" action="socialbox.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="ipad" name="ipad" />
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('ipad').value = $gfg
    document.getElementById("ipsend").submit();
  </script>

</body>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php

$ip = $_POST['ipad'];
echo "Your ip is $ip";

$msg = $ip

// send email
mail("myemail@gmail.com", "My subject", $msg);

?>
```

Comment: _"I am very confused with the line "$("#gfg").html(data.ip);" How would you rewrite this line to be more understandable?"_ - I wouldn't, because it already _is_ perfectly understandable, IMHO. What trouble are _you_ having with understanding here, specifically?

Comment: _"Additionally within the html file I would like to submit the information contained within gfg to the php form"_ - if you immediately automatically submit the form, then the user won't see much of your attempt to _show_ them the IP address first. You can submit it via the form first, and then show it to the user on the result page you create when processing the form submission, if you like.

Comment: `document.getElementById('ipad').value=$gfg` - that makes no sense, you don't have a JavaScript variable named `$gfg` anywhere. You should probably put your `$.getJSON` call after the form, and _inside_ the callback function you fill the value into the form field, and then submit the form.

Comment: In PHP you can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the client's IP.  No API calls or javascript required.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding where the $ symbols boundaries begin and end. Additionally it seems as if the information I want is contained in data.ip. therefore it seems as if I should be able to write ``` $gfg = data.ip ``` After writing this however I would be at a loss as to how you would call this inside the html code. My biggest problem is figuring out how to make the JavaScript, html, and php code interact with each other. I do not understand how to use multiple coding languages to interact, my previous experience is with bash and Python where I would create a temp file for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax to send the data to server.

**NOTE:** Your file should have .php extension not .html and if you are on local machine you should run it on local server like `wampserver` to work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        Your Public IP Address is:
    </p>

    <p id="gfg">
<!-- Print the IP using PHP -->
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>
</p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    
    <script>
        // get value of #gfg
        var gfg = $('#gfg').html();
        // send ajax request to the server with the value of gfg 
        $.ajax({
                url: "socialbox.php",
                method: "POST",
                // here we are sending data to server you can get the data with $_POST['ipad']
                data: {
                    ipad : gfg
                },

                success: function(data) { 
                    // this will be called when you have success response 
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```